# Add a second domain resolved to a single elastic beanstalk application

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

I have an existing Elastic Beanstalk application mapped to a my domain. I now need to migrate this service to use a new domain, since the old one is being retired. However, during a migration phase I need to maintain both mappings.

So, today I have the EB set up with a HTTPS listener on port 443 using a SSL cert we can call `*.foo.com`. Let's say the EB URL is `hello.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`

I then have a Route 53 Alias record for `hello.foo.com` pointing to `hello.eu-west-1.elasticbeanstalk.com`.

Requests to `https://hello.foo.com` goes to the EB application, listening on port 443 and using the `*.foo.com` SSL certificate. So far, so good.

Now let's say I've purchased `bar.com`, and I need `https://hello.bar.com` to point to the same EB application. How is this possible?

If I set up a new `A` record for `hello.bar.com` to point to the EB, the domain name resolves, but the certificates don't match (obviously).
Same if I set up a `CNAME` record.

Since I cannot add a second listener to the EB using port 443 and the `*.bar.com` certificate, I found myself quite short of options. So far I've come up with:

1. Clone the EB environment to a new one and use the new certificate with that one to point `hello.bar.com` to `https://hello-new.eu-west-1-elasticbeanstalk.com`.
2. Use CloudFront in front of the EB, and then set up an `A` record for `hello.bar.com` to point to `xxxxx.cloudfront.net` which in turn points to the EB URL.

Are there more or better ways of doing this? What is the best approach to this situation? Once my new domain is up and all my clients are using the new domain, I want to remove the old `foo.com` domain, but I need `foo.com` and `bar.com` to work in parallel during the migration phase. Also, it seems a bit unnecessary to put CloudFront in front of the ELB - this is an authenticated API and caching will not be possible anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add multiple certificates to the ALB in order to correctly answer both `*.foo.com` and `*.bar.com`

An old guide can be found [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-application-load-balancer-sni/)

Comment: Yes, thanks. I found out that ALB supports this, but classic LB does not, which this legacy application was using. Trying to set it up using ALB.

Comment: The problem for me was using an ancient EB setup with classic LB. When creating a new application using new AMI and ALB, multiple certificates worked fine.